# Unable to setcookie in any browser

Tags: php, setcookie

So I have done a lot of reading on setting cookies and still cannot find what I am doing wrong here. I started with an `if` statement to include another script but it soon became clear the cookie wasn't setting so I simplified it and made it just to echo so I could see if it was setting. Its not.  I am including it above the `<html>`.

I am setting the cookie and then refreshing and no matter how many times I refresh it is still returning a `NULL` result in the `echo` command.

- The `setcookie` is above all of my html, cookies can't be set after any output??
- The value is set, and domain.
- All browsers have cookies enabled, and friends have tested this for me so its not local.
- Its not the server, I asked my host.
- I have even copy/pasted code from [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to no avail.
- And of course checked SO a few mil times.

  ```
  $var='Something';
  setcookie ("Name", "$var", time()+3600, '/', 'website.com');
  echo $_COOKIE["Name"];
  var_dump($_COOKIE["Name"]);
  var_dump ($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS);
  ```

`echo` returning `NULL` and `var_dump` returning `Array(0)`

I am going mad, is there something wrong in my code, what am I missing?

Comment: What have you read, for example?

Comment: Have you checked permissions?

Comment: PHP manual , the about PHP website, about ten posts on SO, tutorials on setting cookies

Comment: Well, did you try "Common pitfalls" section in the manual?

Comment: Cookies are not available in `$_COOKIE` until the next client request.

Comment: If you read my post you will see that I mention I have refreshed the page many times

Comment: @AdamBrown The code example you've included is misleading, which is why the comments have alerted you about it. Setting a cookie and then immediately outputting its value is not the right way.

Comment: Have you checked response headers in your browser to see if the cookie is present in them?

Comment: @Mido permissions for *what?*

Comment: Also, make sure `website.com` matches your own domain.

Comment: @Gumbo you should have written this in answer section.... Thanks......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most frequent problem with setting cookies (or any other header) is, that it has to be set before you send first output character. There may be an invisible character before your script (like BOM or whitespace). If you use includes, thare may be a whitespace after the closing tag of your included script.

Comment: This was it. I just fixed it just before you posted actually. The code was starting line 2 and even just that was enough to ruin it.

Comment: Removing whitespace characters before that function worked.

Answer (score 0):

To debug cookies, one have to debug HTTP headers.
So, get yourself a Firebug, switch to Net tab and watch request and response headers, if you can see any cookie sent by server or returned by browser.

If there will be no trace of cookies - there is some error on the server side then. You need to enable error reporting and displaying in order to see them

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

is a quick and dirty way